# How to agregate multiple traffic at Layer 2/3 between different vendors devices?

Tags: switch, router, switching, hp

[image: How to agregate multiple traffic at Layer 2/3 between different vendors devices]

---

Hi.

I have network design like at above picture. There are 3 floors and each one is stapled by one switch. All 3 floors are connected to the MAIN Switch which is connected to the Edge router`s interrior switch only by one cat. 5e cable. That means that 3 floors use only one 1GB Ethernet connection.

I have 2 spare cables which I would like to use to provide better communication accross my network. The plan is to connect each floor by separate cable (3 x 1 GB) within one address network range - 192.168.1.0/24 because there are no VLAN`s.

I can`t connect all 3 cables just like that because of Spanning Tree and frame storm when  multiple connections between single switch.

CloudCore has interior switch stapled into one bridge. HP switches has one single switch with default VLAN.

**What would be the best practice and how can I force MikroTik CloudCore and HP MAIN Switch to use all 3 cables (one cable should carry all traffic from single floor) ad the same time ?**

Comment: as I remember, by default you shall have a VLAN 1, traffic untagged, so that is the vlan to refer to if asked. Cheer

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I made Trunk at HP using LACP Active and I made bonding at CloudeCore using balance-rr which gave me load balancing at all 3 Ethernet cables between floors and also backup if cables get failure :D

Comment: It's separate question. But look at this traffic in torch or in sniffer.

Comment: A suggestion: don't use balance-rr, it's bad because of out of order delivery. If possible, use 802.3ad (if it is linux, the bonding mode 4 is the right one), then the devices will talk with each other (using LACP) and negotiate proper etherchannel.

Comment: What if it is the Linux ? About what device You are talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

For the HP 1810

1. Go to "Trunks"
2. "Trunk Configuration"
3. Click "Create" checkbox and name the link then apply changes
4. Go to "Trunk membership"
5. Pick the trunk id that was created earlier
6. Pick the ports you'd like to aggregate then apply changes
7. Save Configuration

For the MikroTik CCR1036

Example Config: */inteface bonding add slaves=ether1,ether2 mode=802.3ad lacp-rate=30secs link-monitoring=mii-type1 \ transmit-hash-policy=layer-2-and-3*

[HP Config Reference](http://hotfortech.wikispaces.com/Link+aggregation+(802.3ad)+on+HP+1800G+%26+1810G)
[Mikrotik Config Reference](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/Bonding#802.3ad)

Comment: At HP isn`t it only agregating ? So that mean that all traffics from floor 1, 2 and 3 wents through all 3 cables ?

I`m trying to set that each floor would have own cable.

Comment: @user3799089, with no L2 or L3 separation (i.e. same VLAN/subnet), you can't do what you are asking.  However, the end result this way is the same as you only have a single 1G link from each floor to the aggregation switch so they can't exceed 1G of the 3G capacity to the MicroTik. The bonus is you have redundancy for all three floors if you lose a link.

Comment: Even if I "cut" CloudeCore internal switch into smaller switches ?

Comment: that "cut" means creating VLANs, then yes, by properly setting per-VLAN/per-instance STP costs, you will be able to map one VLAN to one cable and use the other 2 cables in case of failure. But using etherchannel/portchannel/bonding/trunks/teaming is far superior

Answer (score 0):

From the information here the HP1810-24G supports LACP
http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=4AA2-6799ENW&cc=en&lc=en

Have not played with microtik but their documentation was very easy to google:
http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/Bonding
http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/Bridge

The current (and future) troubles I think you may be encountering are possibly with the HP1810, I have deployed the Version1 of these HPs in the past and found out they were really intended for cheap access switches, did not have a cli and did not properly support spanning-tree and had to rely on the upstream switch/aggregator which then was an old Layer2 dell powerconnect 5224.

Being a HP shop, perhaps you could consider replacing the HP1810-24G with a more featured/robust HP switch that fully supports stp, rstp, mstp and the other networking features that you require?